# Error al consumir WebService con Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, webservice

Estoy consumiendo un web service, al dar la url en el navegador si veo el xml con todos sus métodos pero al consumir me lanza este error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

El código del cliente que tengo es:

```
Private Sub btnPruebaFirma_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPruebaFirma.Click
    Try
        Dim ArchivoCerByte As Byte()
        Dim ArchivoKeyByte As Byte()
        ArchivoCerByte = File.ReadAllBytes("ArchivoCer")
        ArchivoKeyByte = File.ReadAllBytes("ArchivoKey")
        Dim WS As New ServicioDeFEAClient()
        Dim Firmante As ServicioDeFEA.FirmanteO = New ServicioDeFEA.FirmanteO()
        Firmante.RFC = "RFCRFCRFCRFC"
        Firmante.Area = "AREAX"
        Firmante.CargoFirmante = ""
        Firmante.Certificado = ArchivoCerByte
        Firmante.Key = ArchivoKeyByte
        Firmante.Password = "12345678"
        Firmante.EntidadCertificadora = 1
        Dim Cadena(1) As String
        Cadena(0) = "a"
        Cadena(1) = "b"
        Dim Firmas As Array = WS.FirmaCadena(Cadena, Firmante)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tal vez tu llamada hace algo que lo rompe?

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar el código del cliente que estas creando? Para poderte ayudar.

Comment: ¿si lo pruebas con alguna herramienta como Insomnia o Postman, también falla?

Comment: Es posible que necesites [añadir credenciales](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/web-service-authentication?view=sql-server-2017) al ws.